# JS failing to populate arrays from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

I have an array of exam result, it contains the date the exam was sat and the grade achieved. I want to put all the grades in one array and the dates in another so I can plot them in a chart.js application. How can I separte them?

Results Array example layout:

```
Results{

[0] {examDate: "2017-10-16T10:30:00", <ResultEntry>grade: A}

[1] {examDate: "2017-15-16T11:00:00", <ResultEntry>grade: C}

[2] {examDate: "2017-16-16T11:30:00", <ResultEntry>grade: B}

[3]{examDate: "2017-20-16T12:00:00", <ResultEntry>grade: B}

}
```

But what I try doesn't populate the two new arrays

```
var dateArray;
var gradeArray;
var counter = 0;

for (members in results) {
    dateArray[counter] = members[0];
    gradeArray[counter] = members[1];
    counter++;//increment storage index
}
```

I have Jquery installed on my project can the `.each` functionality be used to achieve this?

Comment: Try `dateArray[counter] = members.examDate` and `dateArray[counter] = members.grade`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` method by passing a **callback** function.

The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a **provided** function(callback) on `every` element in the calling array.

```js
let results=[{examDate: "2017-10-16T10:30:00", grade: 'A'},{examDate: "2017-15-16T11:00:00", grade: 'C'},{examDate: "2017-16-16T11:30:00", grade: 'B'},{examDate: "2017-20-16T12:00:00", grade: 'B'}];
let dates=results.map(function(a){ 
    return a.examDate;
});
let grades=results.map(function(a){
    return a.grade;
});
console.log(dates);
console.log(grades);
```

You can use also `arrow` functions.

```
 let grades=results.map(a => a.grade);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get values of fields from array elements. Check this:

```
var dateArray = [];
var gradeArray = [];
var counter = 0;

for (var member in results) {
    dateArray.push(member.examDate);
    gradeArray.push(member.grade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `results` is an array, then in this line

```
for (members in results) {
```

`members` is basically the **index value** *0,1,..*

so `members[0]` will be `undefined`

> I have Jquery installed on my project can the .each functionality be
>   used to achieve this?

Yes, but why not use the native `forEach` instead

```
var dateArray = [], gradeArray = [];
results.forEach( function( result ){
  dateArray.push( result.examDate );
  gradeArray.push( result.grade );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the results array is has the following shape:

```
let results = [
    { examDate: "2017-10-16T10:30:00", grade: 'A' },
    { examDate: "2017-15-16T11:00:00", grade: 'C' },
    { examDate: "2017-16-16T11:30:00", grade: 'B' },
    { examDate: "2017-20-16T12:00:00", grade: 'B' }
];
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is perfect for this purpose:

```
let dateArray = results.map(result => result.examDate);
let gradeArray = results.map(result => result.grade);
```

You can also loop over the elements in a few different ways:

```
let dateArray = [],
    gradeArray = [];

for (let result of results) {
    dateArray.push(result.examDate);
    gradeArray.push(result.grade);
}
```

And a solution similar to yours:

```
var dateArray = [],
    gradeArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    dateArray[i] = results[i].examDate;
    gradeArray[i] = results[i].grade;
}
```

You can also push them into the array instead of setting a position to the value:

```
var dateArray = [],
    gradeArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    dateArray.push(results[i].examDate);
    gradeArray.push(results[i].grade);
}
```

And using jQuery **each** as you mention:

```
var dateArray = [],
    gradeArray = [];

$.each(results , function(i, value) {
    dateArray.push(value.examDate);
    gradeArray.push(value.grade);
});
```